# PrimeNG 12, Table scrollHeight

Tags: angular, primeng

After upgrading to v. 12+ I'm having trouble setting the table height to the parent div size.
Table footer shows up right under the table header in case of an empty table.
In prior versions I was able to set the height to 100% and the table body would fill the empty space and the footer would be at the bottom.

I'm setting the scrollable=true, autoLayout=true, scrollHeight=flex.

Basically, I would like the table to fill the parent div whether it has items or not - as if setting the scrollHeight to a hardcoded size, except I need the scrollHeight to adjust to the parent div size.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work with v.12+ ?
Thanks.